# VIM - how to open .html files with django html syntax rather than just html syntax?

Tags: vim, html, file-types, django

I use Django a lot and I just want to open all .html files with the htmldjango syntax rather than html syntax. Is there a way for me to tell vim to open all html files with a htmldjango syntax?

Because at the moment, everytime I open an html file, I have to always click on

```
Syntax
```

and set it to

```
HTML -> Django HTML Template
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To tell VIM to use this style evertytime it loads and HTML file put this into your VIMRC:

> au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html set filetype=htmldjango

You can quickly edit your VIMRC file by executing `:edit $MYVIMRC`.

Comment: That menu is the default list of all installed Vim syntax files, and `syntax/htmldjango.vim` also ships with Vim (version 7.3+)

Comment: @IngoKarkat AH! I didn't find it because i was looking for a file starting with django! Whoops. Glad my answer was still helpful.